# How to set the height for devtools toolbox on Chrome webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm starting the session with the capabilities:

```
  "capabilities": {
    "alwaysMatch": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "browserVersion": "78.0",
      "platformName": "any",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "prefs": {
          "devtools.preferences.currentDockState": "\"bottom\""
        },
        "args": [
          "auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I minimize the toolbox? (set the height = 0)

E.g. on **Firefox** I define the option:

```
 'moz:firefoxOptions': {'prefs': {'devtools.toolbox.footer.height': 0}}
```

Is there a way to do the same on Chrome?

Comment: I have tried "goog:chromeOptions":{"prefs": {"devtools.preferences.InspectorView.splitViewState.vertical.size": 0}}, but I don't see any changes. The syntax itself is correct or should I define it somewhere else?

Comment: This is what I'm trying: "goog:chromeOptions": {"prefs": "devtools.preferences.InspectorView.splitViewState": {"vertical": {"size": 0}, "horizontal": {"size": 0}}}. Result: no changes.

Comment: 1 instead of 0 also didn't help. Can you share the code snippet please? In order to get known where and how exactly to put the values.

Comment: I've also tried with quotes, 0 and 1 values. The syntax looks like: "goog:chromeOptions": {"prefs": "devtools.preferences.InspectorView.splitViewState": '{\"vertical\":{\"size\":0},\"horizontal\":{\"size\":0}}'}. The result is the same.

Comment: Just tried, the same result. 
Interesting that the "devtools.preferences.currentDockState": "\"bottom\"" and "devtools.preferences.panel-selectedTab":"\"console\"" work well, but "InspectorView.splitViewState" doesn't, when I'm trying the same syntax approach.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find any documentation. Can you share it with me? (you mentioned above the `Preferences ` file)

Comment: Oh, finally I've found the solution: `{"devtools.preferences": {"InspectorView.splitViewState": "{\"horizontal\":{\"size\":0.1}}"}}`. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{"devtools.preferences": {"InspectorView.splitViewState": "{\"horizontal\":{\"size\":0.1}}"}}` - this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

All the chrome preferences are available at ***chrome://prefs-internals/*** (should be given in chrome browser).
We can set the currentDockState as 'undocked' and the dev-tools will not be part of the chrome browser window.

For anyone who want to use these prefs in yaml file better use a [tool](https://www.json2yaml.com/) to convert json to yaml file. In that way it will be easy to pass the prefs in yaml format.